# Point of Instantiation for function templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, function-templates

I am learning about templates in C++. In particular, i read about POIs. So i am trying out(by reading and writing) different examples. One such example which is not clear to me is given below:

```
template<typename T>
void g1(T p)
{

}
template<typename T>
void f1(T x)
{
g1(x); // #1: Is this point a POI for g1<T>(x)?
}
//#2: Or is this point a POI for g1<T>(x)?


//#3: Or is this point a POI for g1<T>(x)?
int main()
{
f1(7); // this point cannot be a POI 
}
// #4 I know that this point 4 is a  POI for f1<int>(int) but is this point also a POI for g<T>(x)?
```

In the above snippet, i know that point `#4` is a POI for `f1<int>(int)`. But is point `#4` also a POI for `g1<T>(x)`? I know that in the statement `g1(x);` the name `g1` is an **unqualified dependent name**. I also know that the POI

> for a reference to a function template specialization to be immediately after the
> nearest namespace scope declaration or definition that contains that reference.

This is why point `#4` is a POI for `f<int>(int)`. But then similarly, point `#2` should be a POI for `g1(x);`. But i am not sure where is the POI for `g1(x);`. So what are the rules for finding the POI for an unqualified dependent name like `g1`.

My questions are:

1. Is point `#4` also POI for `g1<T>(x)`? If yes then what are the rules for finding the POI for an unqualified dependent name like `g1`.
2. According to the statement i quoted(which is from C++ Templates: The Complete Guide), shouldn't point `#2` be a POI for `g1<T>(x);`. I guess this boils down to whether the statement `g1(x);` refers to a function template specialization. If yes, then according to the statement quoted, point `#2` should be a POI for `g<T>(x);`. I might be wrong here.
3. What will change if i remove the statement `f1(7);`. To my understanding there will be no POI in this translation unit anymore. But i am not 100% sure of this. Or removing `f1(7);` will make the program ill-formed now.

Comment: This question is too broad. You are mixing overload resolution, point of instantiation and unqualified lookup all in one.

Comment: @PasserBy: I wouldn't say it's too broad; it's just confusion caused by a topic that isn't exactly obvious. The question itself is simple: what's the point of instantiation.

Comment: @PasserBy I can edit out(remove) the ordinary function definition `void g1(int){}` if that will make the question more specific, but my question is not regarding overload resolution. My concern is about POI only. I know that an ordinary function will be choosen over an equally matched function template.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'd say `void g1(int)` is muddying the waters, at the very least.

Comment: @Mike Yes, please do, if that's not your concern.

Comment: @PasserBy Done. Check out the edited question. I have removed `void g1(int){}`.

Answer (score 1):

The point of instantiation for a function template is on the surface pretty simple: it's the place where the compiler first sees a concrete function.

`g1` is a function template; it is a compiler construct which generates a family of functions based on template parameters. `g1<int>` is a concrete function, a product of the compiler instantiating the template `g1` to produce a real function.

When the compiler sees `g1(x)` in `f1`'s definition, it sees that `x` is an expression whose type is dependent on a template parameter. But the compiler doesn't know what the template parameter is yet. So it has no idea what `g1(x)` would do. Yes, it can see the function template `g1`, but because `x` is at this point *unknown*, it doesn't know what template parameters to `g1` it would pass.

As such, it cannot instantiate the template at that point. It can only figure out how to instantiate `g1` through `g1(x)` when `f1` is itself instantiated.

Therefore, C++ defers the point of instantiation of a template function to the first place where the compiler has full knowledge of any potential template parameters. The expression `g1(x)` only gets meaning when an instantiation of `f1` happens. Therefore, if you do something which causes `f1<int>` to be instantiated, `g1<int>` will be instantiated at the same point.